# Google API - Authentication setup and .NET client

Tags: api, authentication

I'm trying to achieve two things from my C# client application using Google API.

- List all users of my google directory
- Get metadata of all emails for each user

It appears, however, that my service account configuration is giving me issues. This is what I have done.

1. Created project in console.cloud.google.com
2. Enabled *Admin SDK* and *Gmail API* from API's and Services
3. Created Service Account with Domain-Wide delegation and obtained credentials.json file.

[image: Service Account setup]
4. On admin.google.com I went to *Security* / *API Controls* and manage Domain-wide delegation. From here I added new API Client from my Service Account client id and assigned the following scopes:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly

[image]

Finally, when I want to try to retrieve users list I get error: *Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential*

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("..\\..\\..\\credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
        var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("..\\..\\..\\credentials.json");

            var dirservice = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "testbuildingnomiproductname",
            });

            var listReq = dirservice.Users.List();
            
            Users allUsers = listReq.Execute();

            int counter = 0;
            foreach (User myUser in allUsers.UsersValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*" + myUser.PrimaryEmail);
                counter++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(counter);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't arbitrarily retreive data from users who you don't have an existing token in your system.   Easiest way to effective do what you're attempting is:  When a user logs into your site, Store the email from the login in your own DB, that way you have access to the token to make the request.

Comment: To clarify more.  1. Google uses OAuth,  so I don't think you can use Basic Authentication.  2. If you follow the OAuth flow you will need to request a code, and use that code from the Server to obtain a token.

Comment: I think the purpose of Service Accounts and Domain Wide Delegation is exactly to be able to perform these actions. E.g. this examples shows how to update email signatures of all users.https://moometric.com/integrations/gsuite/use-gmail-api-update-signatures-gsuite-users-php/

 Maybe I have misunderstood something?

Comment: are you trying to get the the service account email or the emails of all the users who use your applicatio

Comment: My application will analyze the emails metadata of all users in my google directory. For this I'm using a service account to 1) list all users on my directory 2) Foreach user analyse their emails metadata

Comment: I'm not familiar with a way to obtain all of the user other that storing them through OAuth.  I didn't read up on service accounts so maybe that will work out for you.  If you can't get it working ping me on here and I can explain how to get the emails via the OAuth work flow